# Access instance of class from MainWindow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have an application with MainWindow and another class called MyClass. MyClass has a method in it that I need to access from the MainWindow class. MyClass is loaded when the application loads. How do I call the method in MyClass from MainWindow without creating a new instance of MyClass:

```
MyClass class = new MyClass();
```

?

Comment: Where are you creating the instance of `MyClass` ??, can you show the code?

Comment: This is my suspicion too. Needs to be public in MainWindow I suspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight forward answer to your question is to mark class method as static. That will allow you calling it from any place.

On the other hand, it's probably is not what you really need. Thus, if you create `MyClass` on application start inside Application class then you need to expose `MyClass` instance, for example, through application property. Look at the example code.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Method()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The code of your App:

```
public partial class App
{
    public MyClass MyClassInstance { get; private set; }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClassInstance = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

And the code of window where you call method of your class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((App)Application.Current).MyClassInstance.Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Creating something in the start up of the application and a `static` can both be looked at as globals, but if you use a `static` any other call to that method in `MyClass` elsewhere would not be able to take advantage of instance state.

Comment: @NickFreeman, yes, it's obvious. I described two separate approaches according to details what we have from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very suspect, but you do what you are saying by making that method `static`

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public void MethodInMainWindow()
    {
        // Don't need to create a new instance of MyClass
        MyClass.MethodInMyClass();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void MethodInMyClass()
    {
        //  ....
    }
}
```

[Here is a little bit of documentation on static vs instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: the code is wrong needs static also in MethodInMyClass declaration. i edited it but it was rejected. don't  know why.

Comment: @iltzotz yes, i corrected it. That was the most important part of the post. I don't know why your edit was rejected.